# How do i extract the contents in HTML tags that only have <p>

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just got into web scraping and I'm using beautifulsoup to perform web scraping but I only want to extract contents just with the "p" tags. So I want to ignore tags if there are additional class/style/etc...

Example:

```
<p>what I want to extract</p>

<p class="copy">what I do not want to extract from HTML page</p>
```

So far I can only extract all the "p" tags with this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

URL = input("Enter url to scrape: ")
content = requests.get(URL)
soup = BS(content.text, 'html.parser')
content_p = soup.find_all('p')
print(content_p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
soup.findAll(lambda tag: len(tag.name) == 1 and not tag.attrs)
```

Refer - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to remove all unwanted encodings like '\u2060' '\xa0'?

Comment: you can use something like this - badString = "Foo<!-This comment is malformed.-->Bar<br/>Baz"
BeautifulSoup(badString)